# mysql How to change certain row with random number

Tags: mysql

I need to change one row to all random number like between 90-470 is it possible to do it ?
I have tried to manually change it bit there are too any record

Comment: i think you are asking for certain column instead of row? isn't it?

Comment: It's vertical not horizontal so I think it's row?

Comment: Ya it's column I just Google it sorry haha what should I do for it?

Answer (score 0):

I think these sql will helpful to you.

Bottom SQL retruning random number between 90-470.

```
SELECT FLOOR(90+RAND()*(470-90))
```

Comment: Sorry I ain't good in sql do the select floor means the new of the row?

Comment: Sorry it's column not row so what should I do? The columns name is sold

Answer (score 0):

put number of "mt_rand(90,470)" as number columns you have,

$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename(  mt_rand(90,470),mt_rand(90,470)   ) ");
if you want to change existing data user "ALTER" insted of "INSERT".

Comment: Sorry it's column not row so what should I do? The columns name is sold

Answer (score 0):

Let the table be called Data with two columns id and value.

> +----+-------+
>   |  id  |  value  |
>   +----+-------+
>   |  1  |  10  |
>   |  2  |  11  |
>   |  3  |  12  |
>   |  4  |  13  |
>   |  5  |  14  |
>   +----+-------+

Now, we can use Rand() to generate a random number between 0 and 1 and use it to generate the required random nos as

```
floor(rand()*(470-90) + 90)
```

The required SQL query for mysql will be

```
update Data set value = floor(rand()*(470-90) + 90) where id in (select * from  (select id from Data) as X);
```

Note: You need the 
    select * as X
 because mysql doesn't allow to update the same table used in from clause. Hence, this creates a temporary table.

Comment: @Eric Tan  Did my answer solve your issue? If so, please accept it so that others can find it useful.